# std::vector vs std::initializer_list issue: undefined bahevior

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, initializer-list

I have this helper method to append to a linked list (code below):

```
void append(const std::initializer_list<T>& vals) {                               
            for (const auto& val : vals)                                                    
              append(val);                                                                  
}
```

I first tried to append 1,5,7,9 with std::vector like this:

```
void append(const std::vector<T>& vals) {                               
            for (const auto& val : vals)                                                    
              append(val);                                                                  
}
```

But it filled the linked list with 0,0,7,9 instead of 1,5,7,9 . Any ideas why?

Here is the entire code:

```
    template <typename T>                                                               
    class LinkedList {                                                                  
    private:                                                                            
      struct Node {                                                                     
        const T& val_;                                   
        std::shared_ptr<Node> next_ = nullptr;                                          
        Node(const T& val) : val_(val) {}                                               
      };                                                                                
    public:                                                                             
      std::shared_ptr<Node> head_ = nullptr;                                            
      std::shared_ptr<Node> current = nullptr;                                          

      // could be optimized                                                                                 
      void append(const std::initializer_list<T>& vals) {                               
        for (const auto& val : vals)                                                    
          append(val);                                                                  
      }                                                                                 

      void append(const T& val) {                                                       
        if (!head_) {                                                                   
          head_ = std::make_shared<Node>(val);                                          
          return;                                                                       
        }                                                                               
        current = head_;                                                                
        while (current->next_)                                                          
          current = current->next_;                                                     
        current->next_ = std::make_shared<Node>(val);                                   
      }                                                                                 

      template <typename Func>                                                          
      void for_each(Func f) {                                                           
        current = head_;                                                                
        while (current) {                                                               
          f(current->val_);                                                             
          current = current->next_;                                                     
        }                                                                               
      }                                                                                 


    };                                                                               

    int main() {                                                                     
      LinkedList<int> lst;                                                           
      lst.append({1,5,7,9});                                                         
      auto printer = [](int val) {                                                   
        std::cout << val << " ";                                                     
      };                                                                             
      lst.for_each(printer);                                                         
      std::cout << '\n';                                                                            
    }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to see what it is doing?

Comment: Why do you have arbitrary amounts of right-trailing spacing?

Comment: The node stores a dangling reference in both cases.

Comment: _"Here is the entire code"_ Nuh-uh. Read [MCVE]

Comment: @NathanOliver I have not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I copied it from VIM in my terminal. And ok, I'll see  what I can do to create an MCVE.

Comment: Next time please clean it up before posting.

Comment: @John Then you should.  It is very important skill to have and it most cases it can find most of your problem.  Here is a good link on how to debug small programs: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One programming error here is that your Node stores a reference `const T& val_;`. Store the value instead `const T val_;`.

Comment: Oh, so I'm guessing then there's undefined behavior and that's why I saw that it worked for initializer_list and not for vector?

Comment: Also you mention "One programming error". Do you see others?

Comment: @John That was the first thing I noticed because I avoid reference members. I do not spot anything else.